# Consuming a per session WCF service in a WPF application

Tags: wpf, multithreading, wcf, caliburn.micro, coroutine

I'm not really sure how to handle the scenario I have in a good code manner.

The basic of the criteria of my work is this:

- A WPF application that consumes a WCF service
- The service uses per session instancing
- The session starts soon after application is started and should live through the application lifetime (with small exceptions)
- Some method calls in a session must precede and be finished before others are called

This means I will have to be able to have one instance of a proxy client throughout the whole application. I will also have to be able to handle async calls, so the client won't hang up, but at the same time ensure they are finished.

My technical understanding go WCF is limiting enough to not know if certain scenarios would work as intended. So I'm going to list my uncertainties:

- When does a session start and when does it end. Is it based on the creation of clients or could a separate client instance access the same session if the first would go faulted.
- What is the best way to handle exceptions through a WCF service
- Is ChannelFactory something I should look at to help me put here.

So what I did in the first iteration to try to solve some of these problems.

- I used dependency injection to inject the client instance throughout the classes of my WPF application (I'm using MVVM) to ensure the same instance is everywhere.
- I made the service reference using the asynchronous generation method to get the Begin and End versions of all methods to ensure the calls would be async
- I used the Coroutine (IResult interface) feature of the Caliburn.Micro framework to ensure one async action is finished before the other begins (have no idea if this is a proper usage or if it is a smart move at all).

Problems I still have is of course how to handle a faulted state of the client. I'm assuming right now that I could reinstance the client and either rescue the session or I could actually just set it up again as it was. I now need to reinstance it everyplace I injected it in with the same new instance.

So I though perhaps it would be best to create a ClientManager class that would wrap the Client. That way I could inject this ClientManager and reinstance inside of him if needed. I guess I should expose him outwards to be able to make method calls but it would be great if I could error handle inside him in somehow. I'm just having a hard time testing my methods and I'm never certain it will work properly in integration because I don't understand all of the inner workings of WCF, coroutines and threading.

Is there anyone out there with more experience then me in these matters that could give me a few pointers or at least tell me how WCF works in these situations ( per session ) and what I'm doing wrong and what right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WCF supports sessions out-of-box, so I would recommend starting with [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733040.aspx) MSDN article.

At a very high level, first you set `SessionMode=SessionMode.Required` in your `ServiceContract`. And then, set the `IsInitiating=True` and `IsTerminating=True` properties on your OperationContract's to mark the start and end of each session.

However, note that WCF limits concurrent sessions by default to [16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10614903/servicethrottling-default-values) to prevent [DOS attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1788760/why-does-maxconcurrentsessions-default-to-such-a-low-value-and-what-is-a-safe-v), but you can always up the value. Also, you would have realized that the session is valid as long as its host (IIS / Windows Service / other) is not recycled.

On a related note, I have used [WCF Durable Services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb412184%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) earlier - which are meant to persist the state of your WCF service in a data-store (default is SQL Server). Ofcourse, there is a performance hit here. Suggest reading [further](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5313407/is-wcf-durable-services-the-right-choice) to see if this is the right choice for you.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes the service is using a out of the box per session instancing. What I'm not sure on is when this session starts, when it ends. You mention those IsInitiating and IsTerminating properties and I will look into them. So I could create the session originally but if I create a new instance of the client, how do I tell it to intercept that specific session.

Comment: Sessions in WCF do not behave like ASP.NET in the sense that there is no global API like HttpContext.Current.Session. You need to hold on to your WCF proxy, but I do know it gets lost once it faults. The closest I have done to preserve and restore state in a WCF proxy is via Durable Services. [This](http://weblogs.asp.net/gsusx/archive/2007/06/14/orcas-durable-services.aspx) blog post will give you more details if you are interested.

Comment: Hmm, Durable services seem to persist the service, but I don't care about that. I just want the instance of the Service object to stay alive even if the clientProxy dies and a new clientproxy should be able to connect to it.